# Extracting image channels via vImage comes with side effect

Tags: ios, image-processing, core-graphics, accelerate-framework, vimage

I'm trying to use the [`vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1533144-vimageconvert_argb8888toplanar8) API to extract RGB channels. Suppose the following `inputImage` is a solid white image from: https://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/1080x1920/1080x1920-white-solid-color-background.jpg

Here is my code:

```swift
let inputImage = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "1080x1920-white-solid-color-background.jpg")

guard let sourceCGImage = inputImage.cgImage,
      let sourceImageFormat = vImage_CGImageFormat(cgImage: sourceCGImage),
      var sourceImageBuffer = try? vImage_Buffer(cgImage: sourceCGImage,
                                                 format: sourceImageFormat) else {
    fatalError()
}

let componentCount = sourceImageFormat.componentCount
var argbSourcePlanarBuffers: [vImage_Buffer] = (0..<componentCount).map { _ in
    let bitsPerPixel = UInt32(8)

    guard let buffer = try? vImage_Buffer(width: Int(sourceImageBuffer.width),
                                          height: Int(sourceImageBuffer.height),
                                          bitsPerPixel: bitsPerPixel) else {
        fatalError("Error creating planar buffers.")
    }

    return buffer
}

vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8(&sourceImageBuffer,
                                &argbSourcePlanarBuffers[0],  // R
                                &argbSourcePlanarBuffers[1],  // G
                                &argbSourcePlanarBuffers[2],  // B
                                &argbSourcePlanarBuffers[3],  // A
                                vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))

print("Image H: \(sourceCGImage.height), W: \(sourceCGImage.width)")
let capacity = sourceCGImage.width * sourceCGImage.height
print("capacity: \(capacity)")

// Repeat the following code for other 3 channels
let channelDataPtrR = argbSourcePlanarBuffers[0].data.bindMemory(to: Pixel_8.self,
                                                                 capacity: capacity)
let channelRawDataR = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: channelDataPtrR, count: capacity)
let channelDataR = Array(channelRawDataR)
var histogramR = [Double](repeating: 0.0, count: 255 + 1)
channelDataR.map { histogramR[Int($0)] += 1.0 }
print("histogramR:")
for (i, px) in histogramR.enumerated() {
    if px > 0.0 {
        print("Pixel Val \(i): \(px)")
    }
}
```

and here is what I got:

```
Image H: 1920, W: 1080
capacity: 2073600
histogramR:
Pixel Val 0: 129600.0
Pixel Val 255: 1944000.0
histogramG:
Pixel Val 0: 129600.0
Pixel Val 255: 1944000.0
histogramB:
Pixel Val 0: 129600.0
Pixel Val 255: 1944000.0
histogramA:
Pixel Val 0: 129600.0
Pixel Val 255: 1944000.0
```

**Question:** How come I'm getting pixel value `0` if the image is supposed to be solid white (i.e. all pixel value = 255?)

Also note that if I'm running the code above using the Xcode's simulator, I'm getting a different number of `Pixel Val 0`, but the total `capacity` is still `2073600`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be because the actual row bytes of your buffer is wider than your image (see *Create Floating Point Pixels to Use in vDSP* in [Finding the Sharpest Image in a Sequence of Captured Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/finding_the_sharpest_image_in_a_sequence_of_captured_images) for an explanation of how row bytes extend beyond an image's bounding box).

If you use the code from [Specifying Histograms with vImage](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/specifying_histograms_with_vimage), you should get the value that you're expecting:

```
     var histogramBinZero = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
        var histogramBinOne = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
        var histogramBinTwo = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
        var histogramBinThree = [vImagePixelCount](repeating: 0, count: 256)
        
        histogramBinZero.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { zeroPtr in
            histogramBinOne.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { onePtr in
                histogramBinTwo.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { twoPtr in
                    histogramBinThree.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { threePtr in
                        
                        var histogramBins = [zeroPtr.baseAddress, onePtr.baseAddress,
                                             twoPtr.baseAddress, threePtr.baseAddress]
                        
                        histogramBins.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { histogramBinsPtr in
                            let error = vImageHistogramCalculation_ARGB8888(&sourceImageBuffer,
                                                                            histogramBinsPtr.baseAddress!,
                                                                            vImage_Flags(kvImageNoFlags))
                            
                            guard error == kvImageNoError else {
                                fatalError("Error calculating histogram: \(error)")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
        for (i, px) in histogramBinTwo.enumerated() {
            if px > 0 {
                print("Pixel Val \(i): \(px)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks @Simon your provided URLs are really helpful! The reason why I'm using `vImageConvert_ARGB8888toPlanar8` is that I also need to find the max intensity across the RGB channel for each pixel. Right now based on the first URL, for each RGB Planar8 I create an intermediate vImage buffer with explicit row bytes, convert it to PlanarF, then run `vDSP_vmax` twice to get the element-wise maximum for the planar elements. Does it sound like a reasonable solution to you?

Comment: I think `vDSP_vmax` is probably your best bet. However, there may be an overhead in the 8-bit to 32-bit conversion. It might be worth trying the regular `max` function, but I suspect vDSP will be faster.

Comment: The best solution is just to write some vector code to calculate this in a single pass.

Comment: Hi @IanOllmann , can you give me some pointers on vectorizing the code with the Accelerate APIs so that it can be done in a single pass? Thanks